# UTF in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm aware that Python 3 fixes a lot of UTF issues, I am not however able to use Python 3, I am using 2.5.1

I'm trying to regex a document but the document has UTF hyphens in it – rather than -. Python can't match these and if I put them in the regex it throws a wobbly.

How can I force Python to use a UTF string or in some way match a character such as that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I deleted the duplicates. Not sure why my browser submitted 3 at once...

Comment: I find that Python had a very good (not perfect) but very good support for strings in various encoding (e.g. utf-8 (it is an *encoding*)) as ell as Unicode (Unicode is not an encoding) strings long before Python 3 therefore don't blame language; just ask a question if you don't know how to do ... .

Comment: I wanted to pre-empt someone telling me about Python 3 or asking if I was using it. Python 2.5 is still a wonderful language and I prefer it over PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a quick test and visit to [PEP 0264: Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), I see you may need to tell Python the whole file is UTF-8 encoded by adding adding a comment like this to the first line.

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Here's the test file I created and ran on Python 2.5.1 / OS X 10.5.6

```
# encoding: utf-8
import re
x = re.compile("–") 
print x.search("xxx–x").start()
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to escape the character in question (–) and put a u in front of the string literal to make it a unicode string.

So, for example, this:

```
re.compile("–")
```

becomes this:

```
re.compile(u"\u2013")
```

Comment: I was putting an r before the string for raw string

Comment: You can also add 'ur' before the string so that it's raw _and_ Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use UTF-8 in a regular expression. UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding where some unicode code points are encoded by 2 or more bytes. You may match parts of your string  that you didn't plan to match. Instead use unicode strings as suggested.